# gRPC extension not installed in the right PHP version in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, grpc

I'm trying to install gRPC extension following the official [guidance](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/php/quickstart/)

I've followed all the steps, but on these final steps, I get this (which I think will matter later)

```
$ cd grpc/src/php/ext/grpc
$ phpize
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

> Installing shared extensions:     /usr/lib/php/20190902/

Here, I checked that folder and found the `grpc.so` file.

At this point, I expected to have the extension installed, I've added `extension=grpc.so` within `php.ini` (apache2 and cli). But it doesn't work.

I tried to **verify** it but it returns false: `var_dump(extension_loaded('grpc'));` => `bool(false)`

Now, I've checked the apache2 log file and I saw this:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'grpc.so'
> (tried: /usr/lib/php/20180731/grpc.so (/usr/lib/php/20180731/grpc.so:
> cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory),
> /usr/lib/php/20180731/grpc.so

**The possible error?**

What I think is, after install the grpc extension it was installed in `/usr/lib/php/20190902/` (as you saw before). But apache is trying to find it in `/usr/lib/php/20180731/grpc.so`

I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I think I edited the right `php.ini` files because when I do `php_info()` I get this:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /etc/php/7.3/apache2
Loaded Configuration File   /etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files /etc/php/7.3/apache2/conf.d
```

Comment: Did you try to just do `sudo pecl install grpc` as mentioned in the link https://grpc.io/docs/languages/php/quickstart/#using-pecl you mentioned?

Comment: `/usr/lib/php/20180731/grpc.so` seems to suggest that Apache was installed with PHP 7.3, while in your command line installation of the extension `/usr/lib/php/20190902/` seems to indicate that your cli PHP is on PHP 7.4. There seems to be a version mismatch there.

Comment: @StanleyCheung I added an answer. Thanks for your help tho.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've solved it. Apparently `pecl` needed to be configurated on what `PHP version` I wanted it to be installed. Something like this, it was being installed on the `latest` version I have, the `7.4`. But I needed it to be in the `7.3` version:

```
# cd ./grpc

# phpize7.3

# ./configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config7.3

# make clean

# make

# make install
```

Answer (score 10):

I did this way instead by specific version of php for pecl and make sure you make your php version as default one in the ubuntu:

```
# modules of php 7.3 (state your correct version)
sudo apt install php7.3-common php7.3-mysql php7.3-xml php7.3-xmlrpc php7.3-curl php7.3-gd php7.3-imagick php7.3-cli php7.3-dev php7.3-imap php7.3-mbstring php7.3-opcache php7.3-soap php7.3-zip php7.3-intl -y

# module require
sudo apt-get install php-pear phpunit

# if you have previous version of grpc, uninstall it
pecl uninstall grpc

# install grpc base on specific version
pecl -d php_suffix=7.3 install grpc
```

Check detail in my article here, I consolidate most related point of grpc that annoyed me for few days too: https://ask.osify.com/qa/11804

Comment: This is the best solution. None of the bazel, make, cmake methods worked on Linux.