# Docker container fails to build when installing GRPC

Tags: php, docker, grpc

I have a `Dockerfile` that when used with my `docker-compose` commands works fine, I'd like to have this docker container built however as GRPC takes 15 mins to install every time I want to run tests in `GitHub Actions`

This is what my `Dockerfile` currently looks like:

```
FROM xxx-base:6

RUN pecl install grpc \
    && docker-php-ext-enable grpc \

WORKDIR /application
```

And I get the following error output:

```
#5 580.4 g++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
#5 580.4 compilation terminated.
#5 580.4 make: *** [Makefile:248: src/core/ext/filters/client_channel/lb_policy/xds/cds.lo] Error 1
#5 580.5 ERROR: `make' failed
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c sudo pecl install grpc     && docker-php-ext-enable grpc WORKDIR /application]: exit code: 1
```

It's worth mentioning in the base container used here I used `pecl` to install `imagik` so I know that command at least partially works. This is a base `PHP 7.4` container.

Any suggestions, I've seen some other posts referring to the memory limit on the docker build, but I'm not sure what to change

Pastebin full stacktrace: pastebin.com/g7iZ2uRn

Comment: Why you so dearly truncate the stacktrace to make it completely worthless??

Comment: The full stack trace would be 90k chars, limit is 30k, This should help: https://pastebin.com/g7iZ2uRn

Comment: Not the whole log file, but starting at `command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1` ...then comes the relevant part. With only the last few lines, this is rather guessing than knowing something.

Comment: @LewisSmith please add that to the question for new comers to see more easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing GRPC in a pipeline takes a long time.
I recommend using the cache of the provider used (bitbucket, github etc ..) or using a base image which is used as the starting point of the Dockerfile

```
FROM baseimage:latest
```

I have implemented an image based on alpine and php 7.4 with extension grpc installed, check it on github gits [click here](https://gist.github.com/FabrizioCafolla/247d09d204af20493186a27b10b0d712)

Comment: This is actually along the lines of the approach we took in the end, compiling our own base image with only GRPC, so I'll give you the green tick because you have nailed the solution

Welcome to SO

Comment: @LewisSmith thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In case `gcc –version` says anything less than 4.9 ...this might be the cause.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62803136/549372) also seems to be related to your scenario... in case PECL fails.

Comment: Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple clang version 12.0.5 (clang-1205.0.22.11)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin

Can't tell if that's 4.2 or 12.x

Comment: Trying `pecl -d php_suffix=7.4 install grpc`

Comment: No Good 
`#5 6.401 2077 source files, building
#5 6.405 running: phpize7.4
#5 6.407 sh: 1: phpize7.4: not found
#5 6.410 ERROR: `phpize' failed`

Comment: This needs to be installed. I can only speak for Linux, where the package is called `php7.4-dev` or `php7.4-devel` or just `php-devel`. Missing that package might eventually add to the problem (which might eventually even stem from `xxx-base:6` already). When GCC version is less than 4.9, this is only suitable for building elder versions (eg. I can build GPRC on CentOS8, but not on CentOS 7, with GCC 4.8.5).

Comment: I'm not great with Linux, `apt-get install php7.4-devel` throws an error saying it can't find that package, what should the command be. Or is that something I need to go and investigate

Comment: On Debian it's `-dev` ...`-devel` is RHEL slang. And are you sure that "configured with" is from inside the container? This seems to be OSX and not exactly Linux.

Comment: The container this is built from depends on `FROM php:7.4-fpm` not sure if that helps

Comment: There is one pesky detail about the container itself, or better said, the PHP which ships with it: "If using PHP 7.4+, PHP must have been installed with the `--with-pear` flag." ...if this shouldn't be the case, you'll have to build PHP, to begin with.

Comment: Okay I'll try 7.3 for a test

Comment: Different errors, hahaha, okay more investigation required